# problem assigning a pointer to a struct in C

Tags: c, coding-style, project

This is the error that I get in my program:

`[Error] cannot convert 'struct(*)[5] ' to 'struct* {aka Contact*}' in assignment`

When I try to do this:

```
typedef struct Contact{
    char FName[];
    char LName[];
} cont;                                                                    

cont AddressBook[SIZE];                                                   

int main(){ 
    cont *adbook = (cont *)calloc (SIZE, sizeof(cont));
    adbook=&AddressBook
}
```

How can I assing the address of my array of structs to my pointer???

Hope you can help me.

Comment: Maybe you mean `cont *adbook = &AddressBook[0];`. Your code wouldn't compile anyway with `char FName[];`

Comment: ^^^^ - and it leaks memory in just two short lines.

Comment: I am new in this. I have this project and I have been stuck for hours trying to solve that problem but still dont get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we declare arrays, It's variable name is actually already a pointer pointing  it's address.

So when you're performing

```
adbook=&AddressBook;
```

It is like saying point to the address of the pointer which points to AddressBook. This is Invalid assignment. (Somewhat like assigning Pointer to Pointer (**) to a single Pointer(*)).

This can be solved easily by removing the '&' operator while assigning to the pointer.
Making it :

```
adbook=AddressBook;
```

That would simply mean "Point to the location of AdressBook.

Happy Coding !

Comment: @Barmak Shemirani is right about the memory leaks. Even I need a solution to that actually.